# Arrow lens won't let me set a nullable property to null

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

Given this (extremely simplified) code :

```
@optics
data class MigrationStatus(val token: String?)

val m = MigrationStatus(null)
```

I can call

```
val m1 = MigrationStatus.token.modify(m) { "some token" }
```

But as the argument type is a non nullable `String`, how can I modify `token` back to `null` ? Of course

```
val m2 = MigrationStatus.token.modify(m1) { null }
```

does not compile.

The same happens when changing `token` type to an `Option<String>` when trying to set it to `None`, but I avoided it as it is now [deprecated](https://github.com/arrow-kt/arrow-core/issues/114) (which I'm not sure I like, but that's another matter).

Did I miss something obvious ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@Optics` compiler generates 2 optics for that property.

`MigrationStatus.token` & `MigrationStatus.tokenNullable` or `MigrationStatus.tokenOption` in the case of `Option`.

This is because there are two different `Optics` that are useful here.

- `Lens` which has `set` & `get` and in this case `Lens<MigrationStatus, String?>
- `Optional` which has `set` & `getOption` and in this case `Optional<MigrationStatus, String>

The first one is the one you'd want to use in this case to be able to set `String?` to `null`.

So `MigrationStatus.tokenNullable.set(null)`.

The latter is more useful for the DSL, and composition of Optics since if instead of `String?` you had another data class or sealed class you'd want to operate on the value only in the case of not-null.

I hope that fully answers your question!